# How to set the rollouts from the Autoware op_local_planner package only on the driveable area (Vectormap)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

EDIT: seems like i don't  have enough karma points to upload an image please check also here:
[link text](https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware_ai_planning/issues/54)

I' am currently implementing an obstacle avoidance scenario in CARLA.

**Required information:**

```
Operating system and version: Ubuntu 18.04
Autoware install From source
Autoware.ai version: 1.13 
checked out this versions: 
- https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/core_planning/tree/openplanner.1.13
- https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/core_perception/tree/openplanner.1.13
- https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/common/tree/openplanner.1.13
ROS distribution and version: melodic
ROS install From source(apt)
CARLA Version: 0.9.6
Package : op_global_planner, op_local_planner
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Normally start the application. . .

- ROS: *roscore*
- Simulator: *DISPLAY= ./CarlaUE4.sh -opengl*
- autoware_bridge_with_manual_Control
- ray_ground_filter.launch
- can2odom
- points_downsample
- ndt_matching
- vel_pose_connector
- lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
- lidar_kf_contour_track
- op_global_planner
- op_local_planner
- pure_pursuit
- twist_filter
- vehiclecmd_to_ackermanndrive
- carla_ackermann_control_node

I load the vector map by using the vector_map_loader node and then i tell the planner to watch for the map data within the autoware rack with the flag "0".

The picture/video shows exactly what my problem is, the vehicle routes the car outside the driveable area. How can I tell the local planner to generate the rollouts only inside the Asian vector_map.

I know there is also some kind of curb detection which unfortunately does not work for me. I think this is because there is no curb data in the sample maps (Town01, ...). Also, this would not solve the problem if there are parts without curbs, e.g. a meadow that should not be driven on either.

I hope you can help me here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402728/how-to-set-the-rollouts-from-the-autoware-op_local_planner-package-only-on-the-driveable-area-(vectormap)/) by [aforlano22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108811/aforlano22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This workaround . . .
https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware_ai_planning/issues/54

. . . worked for me

---

Originally posted by [aforlano22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108811/aforlano22/) with karma: 11 on 2022-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0